# java net URL connection timeout

Tags: java

I am trying to fetch and download file in html format. Following is the code block:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.mydomain.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

    URL url = new URL("http://www.java2s.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Here, when i am trying to Run this java file it show me following error:

```
D:\Build>javac URLReader.java

D:\Build>java URLReader

Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:227)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:977)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:925)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at URLReader.main(URLReader.java:12)
```

I don't think there any problem with code because When i tried to run this code at Home it worked for me. But when i tried it in my office it showed me the error! 
So i guess there must be some kind of blockage in my office.

Can i set any proxy here in code so that it might work?

Comment: Off topic: Why use fully-qualified class names when you have the packages imported?

Comment: I am new to Java! I am not getting what you are saying. Can you Please elaborate

Comment: Refer to the answer from @Cratytus below. But mind you, even after you've checked for the existence of a proxy, that you have two logic errors in your code that will prevent its successful execution.

Comment: I have Updated my question. and still after adding proxy its not working. Is there any logical error!

Comment: Your proxy may not be correct. Try putting the proxy explicitly in IE proxy configuration and see if u get the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy you need to configure `Java` to use it. Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) on how to set your proxy for your network program

Answer (score 1):

Try this as mentioned in this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

```
//Set the http proxy to webcache.mydomain.com:8080

System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.mydomain.com");
System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "8080");

// Next connection will be through proxy.
URL url = new URL("http://java.sun.com/");
InputStream in = url.openStream();

// Now, let's 'unset' the proxy.
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", null);

// From now on http connections will be done directly.
```